# How to find all the words starting with '$' sign and ending with space, in a long string?

Tags: c#, regex, string

In C#, how do I find all the words starting with '$' sign and ending with space, in a long string, using regular expressions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, "(\\$\\w+) ");
```

In the above, `\\w` matches word characters. These are A-Z, a-z, - and _ if I'm correct. If you want to match everything that's not a space, you can use `\\S`. If you want a specific set, specify this through e.g. `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

The brackets around the `(\\$\\w+)` ensures that of a specific match, `matches[0].Groups[1].Value;` gives the value inside the backets (so, excluding the trailing space).

As a complete example:

```
string input = "$a1 $a2 $b1 $b2";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, "(\\$\\w+) "))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
$a1
$a2
$b1
```

The $b2 is of course omitted because it does not have a trailing space.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, but this only returns me the last match from a string, I want to get all the matches.

Comment: I've expended the answer with an example. I don't understand why this would not return all items in your input test. Could you please provide an example input which only returns the last match?

Comment: Oh Sorry, your regex is working perfectly all right, actually I was not looping through each match, I was using your code matches[0].Groups[1].Value; and I was getting only one match. see the following code, it is working properly and returns all matches. adding code in next comment.

Comment: String templateHtml = "Your homepage $OldHomepageUrl has been changed to $NewHomepageUrl and you can now share it with your friends.";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(templateHtml, "(\\$\\w+) ");

            for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
            {
                var match = matches[i].Groups[0].Value;
                Console.WriteLine(match);
            }

Answer (score 5):

You may try it without regular expressions, that may be faster.

```
string longText = "";
    List<string> found = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in longText.Split(' '))
    {
        if (item.StartsWith("$"))
        {
            found.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
After Zain Shaikh's comment I've written a simple program to benchmark, here goes the results.

```
        string input = "$a1 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2 $a2 $b1 $b2";
        var s1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        double first;
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, "(\\$\\w+) "))
        {
        }
        s1.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(" 1) " + (s1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds * 1000 * 1000).ToString("0.00 ns"));
        first = s1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
        s1.Reset();

        s1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        foreach (var item in input.Split(' '))
        {
            if (item.StartsWith("$"))
            {
            }
        }
        s1.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(" 2) " + (s1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds * 1000 * 1000).ToString("0.00 ns"));
        Console.WriteLine(s1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds - first);
```

Output:

```
1) 730600.00 ns

2)  53000.00 ns

-0.6776
```

That means string functions (also with foreach) are faster than regular expression functions ;)

Comment: I think you have not worked on performance optimization, the split method and foreach loop itslef are performance critical, therefore I always try to avoid them, and that is why I asked for regular expression in my question.

Comment: hmm, good example, I am impressed, I once had to work with Split method and foreach loop, they both were performance critical, so we user alternatives.

Comment: for loops often underestimated for being faster compared to more elegant or syntactically sweet alternatives

Answer (score 0):

```
var a1 = "fdjksf $jgjkd $hfj".Split(" ".ToCharArray())
                                     .ToList()
                                     .Where(X=>Regex.Match(X , "(\\$[a-zA-Z]*)").Success);
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply as well, but this only returns me the last match from a string, I want to get all the matches.